# @Test Annotation in TestNG is not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I have installed TestNG(ver:6.8.6.20130517_2218) in Eclipse (Ver: 1.4.2.20120213-0813) on Windows7(64bit). I verified that TestNG is successfully installed

When I write @Test in one of the sample jave file that I created, Annotation(@Test) is not resolved. It is giving Syntax error.What could be the issue? Please see the attached screenshot for more details

Comment: Check you project build path

Comment: no screenshot attached

Answer (score 1):

TestNG only picks the Files with 'test' in the file Name or Public Class.
For Eg : the File name is App.java it won't run the @Test method but if we rename the file to AppTest it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing annotations.

```
 import org.testng.annotations.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers and help. I got the mistake what I am doing:

I am just leaving by writing `@Test` annotation. Instead if I write the annotation along with function this error is not coming. For e.g.

```
@Test 
public void sampletest() { }
```

then the error which I am facing won't come.

Answer (score 0):

For any future visitors, I was also able to fix this issue by making the test method public.

Answer (score 0):

testng annotations not working.

Inclusion of the following (post by Korey Hinton) helped.
 import org.testng.annotations.*; -